# making histogram from a csv file

Tags: arrays, csv, numpy, histogram

I am trying to read a column of data from a csv file and create a histogram for it. I could read the data into an array but was not able to make the histogram. Here is what I did:

```
thimar=csv.reader(open('thimar.csv', 'rb'))
thimar_list=[]
thimar_list.extend(thimar)
z=[]
for data in thimar_list:
    z.append(data[7])
zz=np.array(z)
n, bins, patches = plt.hist(zz, 50, normed=1)
```

which gives me the error:

```
TypeError: cannot perform reduce with flexible type
```

Any idea what is going on?

Comment: you may need to convert from string to number.  i think csv.reader just creates list of strings, and numpy makes array of strings

Comment: Do you need to use `csv`? I think `np.loadtxt` would do a better job here (simpler code, automatic conversion, etc).

Comment: I try and use csv over loadtxt because it deals with non-number fields better, for example column labels. But if the csv only has numbers loadtxt is a good option.

Comment: @Bago - Just FYI, you can specify `skiprows=1` to `loadtxt` to have it skip the column headers. However, the `csv` module will handle csv files with quoted strings containing commas, etc. `loadtxt` is (deliberately) not set up to deal with non-simple delimiters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

modify the sixth line to cast string to numeric

```
    z.append(float(data[7]))
```

with this i got some plot with my made up data.

Answer (score 0):

Here are two options, this one will work if all your columns are made up of numbers:

```
array = np.loadtxt('thimar.csv', 'float', delimiter=',')
n, bins, patches = plt.hist(array[:, 7], 50, normed=1)
```

this one is better if you have non-numeric columns in your file (ie Name, Gender, ...):

```
thimar = csv.reader(open('thimar.csv', 'rb'))
thimar_list = list(thimar)
zz = np.array([float(row[7]) for row in thimar_list])
n, bins, patches = plt.hist(zz, 50, normed=1)
```